# Selectively handling whitespace in ANTLR4 with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, antlr4

I am trying to parse the following grammar.

```
let_expr : LET iden integer;
CHAR     : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z');
DIGIT    : ('0' .. '9');
LET      : 'let'
integer  : DIGIT+;
iden     : CHAR (CHAR|DIGIT)*;
WS       : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r')+ -> skip;
```

Whitespace ignoring is otherwise important, since it's a small fragment of a large grammar, and carrying whitespace tokens everywhere is extremely cumbersome. However, when the parser tries to parse a statement such as `let ab 10`, it naturally ignores all the whitespace between `ab` and `10`, and parses `ab1` as an identifier, and the last `0` as an integer. Obviously, the intention is that `ab` is the identifier and `10` is the integer. I've seen some solutions that rely on Java, but how do I solve this in Python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `integer` and `ident` tokens and `CHAR` and `DIGIT` fragments. White space won't be ignored within tokens, so that will solve your problem. It will also solve another problem that you haven't noticed yet:

With your current grammar `letter` would be interpreted as the keyword `let`, followed by the identifier `ter`. This is because at the beginning of that input, the lexer has the choice between matching `l` as a `CHAR` token or matching `let` as a `LET` token. Given that kind of choice, the lexer will always prefer the longer match (this is known as the maximal munch rule). That's why having your tokens be the individual characters is generally a bad idea. If you make identifiers and integers your tokens, the maximal munch rule will do what you want instead of working against you.

Comment: Making `CHAR` and `DIGIT` fragments, and still keeping `LET` as a token (defined before `IDEN`) would solve all the issues, right?

Comment: @taninamdar Yes, exactly.